# Combining fos_oauth authenticator with single key authenticator

Tags: symfony, authentication, oauth-2.0, api-key

I set up two authentication methods for my api:

- Private token authenticator by following [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html)
- FOSOAuthServerBundle system for access_token auth: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle

Both works like a charm separately.

I tried to combine those systems with this security config:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH: ~
        ROLE_SUPPORT:           ~
        ROLE_ADMIN:             [ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:       [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPPORT, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
        api_key_user:
            id: security.user.provider.api_key

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        oauth_token:
            pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/token
            security:   false

        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            simple_preauth:
                authenticator: security.authentication.authenticator.api_key
            fos_oauth: true

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check

            anonymous: ~
            logout:
                path: /logout
            switch_user: true
```

If I try to get an access token with this curl command:

```
curl "http://localhost:8000/oauth/v2/token?client_id=1_2rqa1al0trwgso8g8co4swsks48cwsckgc8cokswkcgos4csog&client_secret=25a78plm6c2ss044k4skckkwoo8kw4kcoccg8sg0skook4sgwg&grant_type=password&username=test&password=test
```

It works an I get an access_token, but when I try to use it:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8000/api/changelogs.json -H "Authorization: Bearer MmI2OWNkNjhjMGYwOTUyNDA2OTdlMDBjNjA1YmI3MjVhNTBiMTNhMjI0MGE1YmM3NzgwNjVmZWZmYWNhM2E4YQ" | json_pp
```

I get:

```
{
   "error" : "invalid_grant",
   "error_description" : "The provided access token is invalid."
}
```

By deactivating my single_preauth api key authenticator, it's works and I can access to my API.

It seems my api key authenticator block all another system.

Here, my ApiKeyAuthenticator class:

```
class ApiKeyAuthenticator implements SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface, AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    private $userProvider;

    /**
     * @param ApiKeyUserProvider $userProvider
     */
    public function __construct(ApiKeyUserProvider $userProvider)
    {
        $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function createToken(Request $request, $providerKey)
    {
        $apiKey = str_replace('Bearer ', '', $request->headers->get('Authorization', ''));

        if (!$apiKey) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException('No API key given.');
        }

        return new PreAuthenticatedToken('anon.', $apiKey, $providerKey);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {
        $apiKey = $token->getCredentials();
        $username = $this->userProvider->getUsernameForApiKey($apiKey);

        if (!$username) {
            throw new AuthenticationException('The provided access token is invalid.');
        }

        $user = $this->userProvider->loadUserByUsername($username);

        return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
            $user,
            $apiKey,
            $providerKey,
            $user->getRoles()
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return $token instanceof PreAuthenticatedToken && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        return new JsonResponse([
            'error'             => 'invalid_grant',
            'error_description' => $exception->getMessage()
        ], 401);
    }
}
```

But I can't find why.

How to combine this two authenticator methods?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly found how to handle it but not sure it's the better and proper way.

Don't hesitate to suggest improvements on comments! ;)

First of all, remove `fos_oauth` key from `security.yml` file. It should looks like:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        # [...]
        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            # This will handle both oauth access token and simple private token
            simple_preauth:
                authenticator: security.authentication.authenticator.api_key
        # [...]
```

On `ApiKeyUserProvider::getUsernameForApiKey` method, you will search on both custom api key manager and OAuth access token manager.

The complete class should look like this.

```
class ApiKeyUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var UserManagerInterface
     */
    private $userManager;

    /**
     * @var ApiKeyManager
     */
    private $apiKeyManager;

    /**
     * @var AccessTokenManagerInterface
     */
    private $accessTokenManager;

    /**
     * @param UserManagerInterface        $userManager
     * @param ApiKeyManager               $apiKeyManager
     * @param AccessTokenManagerInterface $accessTokenManager
     */
    public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager, ApiKeyManager $apiKeyManager, AccessTokenManagerInterface $accessTokenManager)
    {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
        $this->apiKeyManager = $apiKeyManager;
        $this->accessTokenManager = $accessTokenManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $apiKey
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getUsernameForApiKey($apiKey)
    {
        // FOSOAuth system
        $token = $this->accessTokenManager->findTokenByToken($apiKey);
        if ($token) {
            return $token->getUser()->getUsername();
        }

        // Private key system
        return $this->apiKeyManager->getUsernameForToken($apiKey);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        return $this->userManager->findUserByUsername($username);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedUserException();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Model\User' === $class;
    }
}
```

And voila! Both Private and OAuth token are correctly managed.

Comment: merci for sharing your solution. Can you please share also with the complete declaration of the the services `security.authentication.authenticator.api_key` and the one related to the user provider. Merci beaucoup

Comment: One more question: how did inject `ApiKeyManager`?? I search in the service container and I did not find it! Have you created it by yourself?